# Changing background of one post in a group of posts -JS

Tags: javascript, css

I have a page where at top a full post (Wordpress) is displayed and underneath the post is the full group of posts (title and excerpt) including the one displayed. I want to be able to change the background of the post below (title and excerpt) when it is the same post as the one displayed in full above.

Here's my code:

```
var title1 = document.querySelector(".subhead").innerText.toLowerCase();
var names = document.querySelectorAll('.case-names'),
  result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  result.push(names[i].textContent.trim().toLowerCase());
  if (title1 == names[i]) {
    document.querySelector(".case-bottom").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
};
```

When I use console log, I see title1 = joe smith and that "joe smith" is contained in the names array. I don't get any errors but the background isn't changing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of HTML element has the .case-bottom class?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to put the text in an inline element, like a span, and then apply the background color to the span.

HTML markup:

```
<h1 class="case-bottom"><span>The Last Will and Testament of Eric Jones</span></h1>
```

JavaScript:

```
if (title1 == names[i]) {
  document.querySelector(".case-bottom span").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't test the code, and I had to guess what is your DOM structure. So my code might not match your need exactly, but it should be enough to show you what you should do. I suppose your HTML:

```
<div class="main-post"></div>
<div class="case-bottoms">
  <div class="case-bottom>
     <div class="case-name">Post Title</div>
     <div class="case-excerpt">some text</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

```
let cases = document.querySelectorAll('.case-bottom');
[...cases].forEach(case => {
   let caseTitle = case.querySelector(".case-names").trim().toLowerCase();
   if (caseTitle == title1) {
     case.style.backgroundColor = "red";
     // I always prefer this:
     case.classList.add(".is-reading");
  } else {
     // and this:
     case.classList.remove(".is-reading");
  }  
     
)
```

Comment: This would be really bad and non semantic HTML. I hope this is not the case and you shouldn't recommend this.

Comment: I didn't recommend anything. By looking at the code and goal, I made an assumption.

Comment: Not implicitly, but it's better practice to only give code examples that are actually well written unless stated otherwise. You're also missing a double quote after your class.

Comment: HTML in my answer is just to show which parent I picked, how I selected the title. Nothing more. Also, missing double quotes is nothing to do with my answer.

Comment: No need to be defensive, just giving some structural feedback. Still up to you to what to do with it.

Comment: If I rewrite the above answer as such: 

var title1 = document.querySelector(".blog-subhead").innerText.toLowerCase();
let cases = document.querySelectorAll('.case-bottom');
cases.forEach(cases => {
   let caseTitle = cases.querySelector(".case-names").trim().toLowerCase();
        if (caseTitle == title1) {
            cases.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    });
Then I get the error that trim is not a function.

Comment: Use console.log to see what you are trying to trim. The error suggests ".case-names" is not text. So ".innerText.trim()" can work. But please my us a favor and share your HTML, so we can understand what we are dealing with.

Comment: Thank you to everyone. I got it to work with let caseTitle = cases.querySelector(".case-names").innerText;